# Custom page containing list of nodes separated by content type and date like an Archive

Tags: theming, nodes, 6

How can I create a custom page containing list of nodes separated by content type and date like an Archive?

I think it requires pagination too. So is there any module for this purpose (Drupal 6)?

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

1. Installed and enabled the Views module
2. Installed and enabled the [Archive](http://drupal.org/project/archive) module
3. Enabled the *Archive* view
4. Added the following lines in the template file

   ```php
   print views_get_view(archive);
   print $content;
   ```